# How to change tab bar item controller on touch?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am wondering if it is possible to change the tab bar item controller on touch.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   if(smth)
   {
       [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
   }
}
```

Need functionality like this, but I don't have that in `tabBarController` array of controllers.

Basically, I want to replace controllers at some point.

Comment: You can do this by appdelegate protocol;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate)

If you set an object to be the delegate of a UITabBarController, you will get call back that will give you entry point to some interesting point in the life of the `UITabBar`

---

This doesn't work?

```
[tabBarController.tabBar setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated];
```

Comment: I am already using tab bar delegate, but how to replace specific tab bar item controller ?

Comment: I want to change tab bar item controller and title after i press button in other view controller.

<!-- language: c# NSMutableArray *muteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

SomeClass *some =[[SomeClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[muteArray addObjectsFromArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];

[muteArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:some];

appDelegate.shop.title = @"Changed";

/* Autoreleased array */
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:muteArray];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:array];

[array release];
[muteArray release];
[some release];
-->

Comment: @streetboy - you should consider updating your question, that would place that code in a more readable format and you can tell us what problem you have encounter with your try.